# What's the proper resolution for 18.5 to 30" computers

Tags: display

What's the proper resolution for 18.5 to 30" computers? I've been walking around the store one day, to find 27" monitors with 2048x1152 resolution. That's mostly crap, and I can't bargain them because they'll just choose the best one they have.

Comment: The answer will vary per person and I have VTC'ed as primary oppionon based. That was the third VTC, and the third choosen reason to close. To me that indicates that this is really not a good question for this site.

Comment: Go to the question: Cannot set 1360x768 in DVI connection, VGA works only if EDID is disabled and you will figure out the answer in the first answer

Comment: @Chris - How about just answering our questions instead of telling us "to figure it out"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The de facto standard resolutions for desktop monitors have been 1920x1080 and 1920x1200 for about the last 10 years, as of January 2016.
Other resolutions have always been available, and it seems likely that either QHD or 4K will become the next de facto standard in a couple years.

Comment: You should be right

Comment: Erm... You're right